# 'We amateurs' or 'us amateurs'

Tags: grammar, case

In this sentence should it be 'we' or 'us'?

> Just so things don't get too complicated for **us** amateurs in chess,...

Or

> Just so things don't get too complicated for **we** amateurs in chess,...

Seems like the latter but I'm not 100% sure

Comment: Only use *we amateurs* if it's the subject of the sentence. You wouldn't say *it's too complicated for we*, would you?

Comment: Or you could avoid the problem by saying *Just so things don't get too complicated for amateurs like us in chess,...*

Comment: You can't win with this one. The people who made up a language in which you weren't allowed to say "John and me went" got the upper hand, and for centuries have taught a set of rules which only people who have studied languages like Latin couldunderstand. As a result, a lot of people learnt the message that you weren't supposed to say "me" in any complicated expressions, and had to say "I", and so they said "between you and I", though the inventors of the original rule would say that was wrong. The problem with "we" and "us" is similar, but rarer, so most people don't know what to do.

Comment: Of course one may prefer to use "we" if they think they are in the presence of someone who's going to derail the conversation to take umbrage. Kind of like swearing in front of your grandmother: best to avoid unless she's cool.

Comment: Wherever “us” alone would be correct, “us amateurs” is also correct.

Comment: @ColinFine The worst example I've seen recently: “the wall between my sister and I's bedrooms.” — “my sister's and my” would be better, but perhaps better still to reframe: “my bedroom and my sister's.”

Comment: @AntonSherwood Or "...the wall between my sister's bedroom and mine"

Comment: Thank you all, that's been really helpful and I can see what's happened here now. And Yorik yes, my grandmother would have agreed fully with that

Comment: "...us amateurs" or "we who are amateurs", but not "we amateurs".  Many native speakers get this wrong, so it's not so serious if you do.

Comment: @BadZen I disagree with your comment, in his example only *"us amateurs"* is grammatically correct.

Answer (score 2):

The only correct version is:

> Just so things don't get too complicated for **us** amateurs in
> chess,...

Here we ask the question **"for whom"**? - **us**.

Grammatically speaking **"us"** is an object pronoun and is used in object position, which is the right one in the situation we have here.

**"We"** is a subject pronoun and is used in subject position, like in:

> **We**, amateurs in chess, hope that things don't get too complicated for us.

Comment: "We (chess) amateurs" doesn't need a comma separating the pronoun from the noun, it is the subject.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I remember there was a rule of some kind telling when a comma should be placed after a pronoun, something to do with injective clauses, Michael Swan probably talked about it in his grammar books. Can you explain why there should be no comma in this example?

Comment: The commas are correct in your example because they act as a parenthesis, the sentence remains grammatical when that extra piece of information is removed. But  **We chess players**, **We chess enthusiasts** or **We amateurs** do not need a comma splitting the pronoun from its noun because they are all subjects. I don't think   *we amateurs in chess* as a subject works very well because it is a prepositional phrase.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I'd present it as more of a relative clause after a personal pronoun and since a relative clause that gives more information about the personal pronoun in our case should be separated from the rest of the sentence we must place a comma before and after it. We can say, "We, who are amateurs in chess, hope..."

Answer (score 1):

If the subject is "We + Noun", it precedes the verb (SVO) in a sentence or clause. Examples:

> 1. There are a lot of cat lovers out there that wouldn't dream of having only one cat. Many of us live in multiple cat households. Why not? **[We cat lovers](https://www.petplace.com/article/cats/pet-behavior-training/what-cats-teach-about-love)** know how much a cat can bring into our homes and that more cats mean more feline fun.

> 2. It may be hard for some of us to imagine not having a book to hold, to read, to stroke or to sniff ([**yes, we book lovers** are a strange bunch](https://www.northampton.ac.uk/news/on-a-literary-mission-why-we-engage-with-world-book-day/)), but there are many children and young people who do not have that privilege.

> 3. **We part-time workers** need to be understood by our full-time
>    counterparts. We don’t care less, we’re not less-committed, and we don’t have smaller “cojones” (is that “bottom talk”?) just because we don’t work 80 hours every week at the hospital or clinic.

> 4. Whether working on a remote control monster truck or a BMW 3 series, I've grown to appreciate a strong understanding of the mechanics that make these vehicles work. **As we enthusiasts** know all too well, these mechanical addictions aren't cheap—especially if paying someone else for labor, in addition to costly parts! Source: [JD Cars](https://jd-cars.com/pages/about-us)

And finally,  the following plural nouns are often used to describe people who play chess for passion: *amateurs*, *players*, and *enthusiasts*.

> 5. Attacking the King prematurely is one of the key bad habits **we amateurs** have, and giving up this bad habit and replacing it with establishing imbalances has resulted in a nice increases of my rating.

> 6. Who’s the greatest baseball player of all time: Babe Ruth? Barry Bonds? Wilt Chamberlain or Shaq in basketball? Pele or Maradona in soccer/football? **We chess players** ask the same questions, too, but we at least have an advantage: chess careers can be quite long!

> 7. Employing even a little bit of strategy than having no strategy at all up your sleeve – or, as **we chess enthusiasts** often say, even a bad plan is better than no plan at all.
>    Source: [Chess for Dummies](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Chess_For_Dummies/ENTTzGHlfvcC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22we%20chess%22%20%22even%20a%20bad%20plan%20is%20better%20than%20no%20plan%20at%20all%22&pg=PT197&printsec=frontcover) By James Eade

Answer (score 0):

In situations like this, mentally eliminate the phrase which identifies or explains the pronoun . Now look at the sentence to identify whether the pronoun is a subject (we) or an object (us).

The sentence becomes "Just so things don't get too complicated for we/us." Obviously, "us" is the right choice.